# invalid operation exception was unhandled Update requires a valid UpdateCommand

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, invalidoperationexception

From these codes, I want to edit, add and save data from VB to MS Access permanently.  I created dozens of Visual Basic projects but no progress at all.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub ProductDescBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ProductDescBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click

        Me.Validate()
        Me.ProductDescBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.INVSYSDataSet)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'INVSYSDataSet.ProductDesc' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.ProductDescTableAdapter.Fill(Me.INVSYSDataSet.ProductDesc)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is that "invalid operation exception was unhandled" appears, Update requires a valid `UpdateCommand` from code `Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.INVSYSDataSet)`

If you need the DataSource, I can provide code from another VB project.

*updated second code, help for sql please
*updated srry bout that

Public Class Add_Products

```
Private myConString As String
Private con As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Private Dadapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Private DSet As DataSet
Private DSet2 As DataSet
Private ConCMD As OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim strSql As String
Dim inc As Integer
Dim MaxRows As Integer

Private Sub Add_Products_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    myConString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\larca\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\march16\march16\obj\x86\Debug\INVSYS.mdb"
    con.ConnectionString = myConString
    con.Open()
    Dadapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from ProductDesc", con)
    DSet = New DataSet
    Dadapter.Fill(DSet, "ProductDesc")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DSet.Tables("ProductDesc")

    con.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Using con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(myConString)
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand
            cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE ProductDesc", con)
            Dadapter.UpdateCommand = cmd
            Dadapter.Update(DSet, "ProductDesc")
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Did you define an Update command for the DataAdapter? [OleDbDataAdapter.UpdateCommand Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.updatecommand.aspx)

Comment: what did u mean? creating a command?

Comment: You need to provide the DataAdapter with the SQL for the Update command.  That's what the error message is telling you.  Take a look at the link I provided in my previous comment.

Comment: where can i define it?

Comment: Open MS Access, paste in the sql from your update. You will see that it does not work. You must use valid sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you have not defined an Update command for the DataAdapter.  From [DbDataAdapter.Update Method DataSet, String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19c81fk.aspx): `If INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements have not been specified, the Update method generates an exception.`

To resolve this, assign the `UpdateCommand` an `OleDbCommand` object with your update logic, like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

   Using con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(myConString)
       con.Open()
       Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
       cmd = New OleDbCommand("<your update SQL goes here>", con)
       DAdapter.UpdateCommand = cmd 
       Dadapter.Update(DSet, "ProductDesc")
   End Using
```

End Sub

Simply put your SQL in the `OleDbCommand` and assign it to the `UpdateCommand` property.

Look at this link for a detailed example (and be sure to use parameterized queries like in the example to avoid SQL Injection attacks): [OleDbDataAdapter.UpdateCommand Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.updatecommand.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Comment: i can't do it, can you help me plss

Comment: Can't do what?  Get the code to work?  Write the SQL update?  Post what you've tried (edit your question so it will format properly).

Comment: here i edited the 2nd codes, can u help me please, stuck in my system analysis project 1 days to go

Comment: can't parameterized because im was confuse in parameterizing gridview and i don't know parameterizing yet

Comment: Your SQL command isn't an update - it's a simple SELECT.  An update is something like UPDATE tablename SET columnname = value WHERE someothercolumname = someothervalue.

Comment: srry bout that, i changed it again,do you mean that,please reply if im wrong again

Comment: It's still not an update command - it won't even run.  Have you worked with SQL before?